# Grails Hibernate Session Read Only

Tags: hibernate, session, grails, grails-orm

I have two grails servers:

- Server - has read/write access to the database
- Web - has read-only access to the database, and for every write it sends a request to the server

The problem: How do I make the Web's domain objects read only in one place (config file) for the entire run of the application, instead of writing caching: 'read-only' for each domain class' mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para-phrased from http://www.nabble.com/database-read-only-td20360158.html

If you have **pooled=true** in DataSource.groovy this creates a org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.  You can set the defaultReadOnly property in the BootStrap.groovy:

```
class BootStrap { 

      def dataSource 

      def init = { servletContext -> 
         dataSource.defaultReadOnly = true 
      } 

      def destroy = {} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

with grails 1.3.7

use [dataSourceUnproxied]
instead of [dataSource]